# Qt Android 5.3 Application Size

Tags: android, qt, qt-quick

So I’m new with Qt and tried to create the most simple app (Qt Quick) for my device, just to check load time and size.
For my surprise there was a 32 MB app just for a textinput and a slider.
Am I doing something wrong ?

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are adding many Qt modules. You should include only the necessary ones. This is a quote from BogDan Vatra the man who ported Qt to Android :

> Qt files can go slightly over 40Mb/platform if you are going to use
>   all of Qt modules. Of course your application doesnt need all the
>   modules, so, if your application uses only Qt Quick Controls + Qt SVG
>   + Qt Multimedia + Qt Sensors + Qt XML modules, Qt files (libs + plugins + additional files) are ~20Mb/platform and your APK will be
>   ~10Mb.

You can see [Choosing the right deploying system](http://www.kdab.com/qt-android-episode-4/)